# Constrain function arguments to the same key

Tags: typescript

I'm quite new to typescript and am trying to write some code that takes a number of different shapes of data from different sources and passes them to classes that will aggregate them (one aggregator class per data shape).

To do this, I believe I need a function (called `dispatch` below) that will take a generic type of data and an identifier for the aggregator class of that data but I'm struggling with constraining the parameters enough for typescript to be happy.

This is what I have so far:

```
enum SourceIdentifier {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b'
}

interface DataA {
  prop1: number,
  prop2: number[],
}

interface DataB {
  prop3: number,
  prop4: number,
}

class BaseAggregator<Data> {
  public add(data: Data) {
    // Store the data to be aggregated.
  }
}

class AggregatorA extends BaseAggregator<DataA> {}
class AggregatorB extends BaseAggregator<DataB> {}

const managers = {
  [SourceIdentifier.A]: new AggregatorA(),
  [SourceIdentifier.B]: new AggregatorB()
}

// How to correctly constrain this function?
const dispatch = (data, source: SourceIdentifier) => {
  managers[source].add(data);
};
```

I've tried using generics but am getting a typescript error:

```
const dispatch = <Data, Manager extends BaseAggregator<Data>>(data: Data, source: SourceIdentifier) => {
  /*
   * Type 'AggregatorA | AggregatorB' is not assignable to type 'Manager'.
   *   'Manager' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'AggregatorA | AggregatorB'
   */
  const manager: Manager = managers[source];
  manager.add(data);
};
```

Is it actually possible to constrain a function like this or am I doomed due to the types not existing at runtime? Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to acheive what I wanted by using discriminators like so:

```
enum SourceIdentifier {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b'
}

interface DiscriminatedData {
  discriminator: SourceIdentifier;
}

interface DataA extends DiscriminatedData {
  discriminator: SourceIdentifier.A,
  prop1: number,
  prop2: number[],
}

interface DataB extends DiscriminatedData {
  discriminator: SourceIdentifier.B,
  prop3: number,
  prop4: number,
}

type DataMessage = DataA | DataB;

class BaseAggregator<Data> {
  public add(data: Data) {
    // Store the data to be aggregated.
  }
}

class AggregatorA extends BaseAggregator<DataA> {}
class AggregatorB extends BaseAggregator<DataB> {}

const managers = {
  [SourceIdentifier.A]: new AggregatorA(),
  [SourceIdentifier.B]: new AggregatorB()
}

const dispatch = (data: DataMessage) => {
  const manager: BaseAggregator<unknown> = managers[data.discriminator];
  manager.add(data);
};

// Example
dispatch({discriminator: SourceIdentifier.A, prop1: 2, prop2: [3, 3]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with your generics on the dispatch function. If you need to constrain a generic to be one of a particular set of types you can do so using the union operator (`|`).

By writing something like this in your generics `<Data extends DataA | DataB, ...>` You are constraining the generic type `Data` to be either `DataA`, `DataB` or the union of the two. You can also do this for the generic in your `BaseAggregator` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the constraint to the function and the `BaseAggregator` class, but I'm still getting the same error as I was before. Do I need to add something else too?

Comment: Maybe instead of having a `Manager` generic simply give your `const manager` a type of `BaseAggregator<Data>` ?

Comment: You could also use conditional types: `const manager: Data extends DataA ? AggregatorA : AggregatorB`